# How to remove vertical white lines when using ggsave in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently on R 3.5.3 and my os is osx mojave. When I save a histogram in R using the ggsave-function, I get these very fine vertically oriented white lines. They don't show up in my R-Viewer but only in preview and vs code (and probably other viewers). Please see the screenshot below. A reproducible example would be the following.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggsave)

df <- data.frame(values = sample (c(1:20), size = 1000, replace = T))

histogram <- df %>%
   ggplot(aes(x = values)) +
   geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha = 0.7, position = "identity", binwidth = 1, size = 0) +
   theme_minimal()

ggsave(histogram, file = "histogram.pdf")
```

Is there a way to change this behavior? After saving the figure, I would like to insert it into LaTex and make sure these white lines are gone.

[image]

Comment: When I run this code I don't see any thin white lines. Can you provide a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for your question. Please see the screenshot above.

Answer (score 3):

The `PDF` format is creating these white lines when bars are overlapping. You may be interested to use the `PNG` format to save the plot as it can be seen in the viewer.

Otherwise you may keep the `PDF` format and revise your plot aesthetics by setting `color` and `fill` with the same color. You would also need to adjust the `alpha`.

library(dplyr)
library(ggsave)

```
df <- data.frame(values = sample (c(1:20), size = 1000, replace = T))

histogram <- df %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = values)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), alpha = 1,color = "dark grey", fill = "dark grey", position = "identity", binwidth = 1, size = 0) +
    theme_minimal()

ggsave(histogram, file = "histogram.pdf")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For my work, I would like to have two histograms with binwidth = 1 and alpha = 0.7. How would you manage this?

Comment: You can play with the ```fill``` and ```color``` in the ```ggplot(aes())``` by specifying a the factor your are interested in to split the data. This page may give you a good insight of what you can do for histogram plots in ggplot : https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/228019_f0c39e05758a4a51b435b19dbd321c23.html#13_histogram_plots

Comment: Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I cannot manage to get rid of them. A viable solution is to call two different histograms. This way, one in in the back and the other one in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the dpi. I had this with a map and doubled the dpi to 600 and they disappeared.